# Improving/ Optimizing Performance Query in PHP, MySQL,Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-performance

I have a invoices, invoices_items, order, order_items. Invoices and Orders tables contains around 1 Millions records. Invoices_items and Orders_items tables contains more than 2 Millions records. Items table contains 2 Hundred Thousands records. Now I want to generate a report based on my filter like customers, item categories and more....
Please refer queries.

Running on PHP 5.6. MySql 5.7 and Apache2.

```
SELECT
  `si_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(si.id) AS `siso_id` 
  , MAX(si.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `invoice_items` AS `si_items`
  LEFT JOIN `invoice` AS `si`
    ON si.id = si_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON si_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(si.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (si.approved = 1)
  AND (si.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`

     UNION

SELECT
  `so_items`.`item_id`
  , SUM(qty) AS `qty`
  , IFNULL(SUM(selling_price * (qty)), 0) AS `salestotal`
  , GROUP_CONCAT(so.id) AS `soso_id` 
  , MAX(so.date_transaction) AS `date_transaction`
FROM
  `order_items` AS `so_items`
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS `so`
    ON so.id = so_items.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN `items`
    ON so_items.item_id = items.id
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(so.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
  AND (so.approved = 1)
  AND (so.deleted = 0)
  AND (items.deleted = 0)
    GROUP BY `item_id`
```

When I executed this query for 50 days. It took 1 minute 20 seconds to execute this query.

INDEXES are added in tables

Invoice & Order Tables

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
KEY `approved` (`approved`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`)
```

Invoices_items & Order_items

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
KEY `qty` (`qty`),
```

Explain Query

[Explain Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vdUf.jpg)

I need to increase performance of this query. Could you please guide me how to proceed?

**Show Create Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales_types_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `quote_validity` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `sales_representative_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `account_type_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_exempted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  `finalised` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Not Yet finalised - status=1; Need Approval - status = 2; Approved - status = 3',
  `approved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `approved_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `default_sales_location_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0-Yes; 1-No',
  `generate_do` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `generate_dn` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `do_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cn_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rp_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `dm_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `currency_id` char(36),
  `exchange_rate_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `exchange_rate` double DEFAULT '1',
  `date_transaction` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `approved` (`approved`),
  KEY `branch_id` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `cn_status` (`cn_status`),
  KEY `created_user_id` (`created_user_id`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `do_status` (`do_status`),
  KEY `finalised` (`finalised`),
  KEY `reference` (`reference`),
  KEY `rp_status` (`rp_status`),
  KEY `sales_types_id` (`sales_types_id`),
  KEY `account_type_id` (`account_type_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `date_transaction` (`date_transaction`),
  KEY `default_sales_location_id` (`default_sales_location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `invoice_items` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` double DEFAULT '0',
  `cost_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `list_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `selling_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `unit_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `vat` double DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `special_discount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `price_change_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `remarks` text,
  `vat_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `stock_category_id` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Stockable 2: Service',
  `is_giftitem` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1: Gift Item 0: NO Gift',
  `item_type_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `modified_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `stock_category_id` (`stock_category_id`),
  KEY `item_type_status` (`item_type_status`),
  KEY `vat_id` (`vat_id`),
  KEY `amount` (`amount`),
  KEY `qty` (`qty`),
  KEY `unit_price` (`unit_price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I'd personally say this belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com try posting it there

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: @Isaac, Thanks I have posted also.

Comment: @TimFountain, I have added indexes in the post.

Comment: Please qualify all columns; we don't know, for example, what table `selling_price` is in.

Comment: Are the tables `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  (Why not simply show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: @RickJames, updated show create table in the post. almost same structure for both invoice and order tables

Comment: @rsm - Thanks.  I added to my Answer.  Keep in mind that 'composite' indexes are different than single-column indexes.  Also, indexing a flag is rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when you mean `JOIN`.  In particular, for joining to `si`.

```
WHERE (
    DATE_FORMAT(si.date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2019-01-01'
    AND '2019-02-15'
  )
```

-->

```
WHERE si.date_transaction >= '2019-01-01'
  AND si.date_transaction  < '2019-01-15'
```

so that an index (see below) can use that column

```
WHERE  si.date_transaction ...
  AND (si.approved = 1)
  AND (si.deleted = 0)
```

Add a composite index:

```
INDEX(deleted, approved,   -- in either order
      date_transaction)    -- last
```

Make similar changes to `so`.  Then let's hear how the performance is and see what the `EXPLAIN` has changed to.

**UUIDs**

Beware of UUIDs, they are bulky and slow.  They are especially slow if the entire table cannot be cached.

I suspect you have uuids because I see `CHAR(36)`.

By having `CHARACTER SET utf8`, that means 108 bytes is being used!.  A UUID can be packed into a 16-byte `BINARY(16)`.  This would help with space (and hence speed).

But the real problem with UUIDs is with the randomness.  Once the table becomes huge, the system becomes I/O-bound since the 'next' UUID is unlikely to be cached.

Consider switching to `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids.  This is much preferred for single-server systems.  If you need to generate ids from multiple locations, you may still need UUIDs.

[*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) on UUIDs.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James. I will add composite indexes & check the performance. application is running on multiple locations. so we have to use UUID.